# Trying to login in Confluence using python

Tags: python, curl, server, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am new to confluence and I have been given a task to access our Company's  Confluence's pages programatically.

I found about the REST API call and python's [atlassian-python-api](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/)  library but none of them seems to be working for me.

The url of confluence page which I am trying to access looks like this :

https://aaa.bbb.com/ccc/ddd/viewpage.action?pageId=80628668

I made below curl request :

```
curl -u myLoginusername:myLoginpassword-X GET "https://aaa.bbb.com/ccc/ddd/viewpage.action?pageId=80628668" | python -mjson.tool
```

but I get below response:

```
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 4933 100 4933 0 0 4933 0 0:00:01 --:--:-- 0:00:01 39464
No JSON object could be decoded
```

when i use [atlassian-python-api](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/)  in my python script :

```
from atlassian import Confluence
confluence = Confluence(    url='https://aaa.bbb.com/ccc/ddd/viewpage.action?pageId=80628668',    
username='myLoginusername',   
password='myLoginpassword')
status = confluence.get_page_properties(page_id=80628668,)
with open('test.html','w') as f:        f.write(status)
print(status)
```

I am redirected to the login page. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong in both cases?

P.S. : I dont have option to create API token in my account.

Answer (score 1):

give only the base url 
example:

```
from atlassian import Confluence
confluence = Confluence(url='https://aaa.bbb.com/',    
username='myLoginusername',   
password='myLoginpassword')
status = confluence.get_page_properties(page_id=80628668,)
with open('test.html','w') as f:        f.write(status)
print(status)
```